# Automounting an sd card results ownership change

Tags: permissions, rsync, automounting

I want to have a "backup" on an SD card that I have always plugged in my laptop.
I got the `UUID` and put in `/etc/fstab/`, the entry is `UUID=xxxx /home/enrico/sd_card exfat defaults 0 2`. 
I followed [these](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/how-to-automount-file-systems-on-linux) instructions.

To make said "backup", I run `rsync -avP source_dir sd_card_dir`.
It spits out `Operation not permitted` and if I look at the permission, `root` is the owner. 
Nor `chmod`, neither `chattr` are permitted even with `sudo`.
What am I missing, am I doing something wrong in the `/etc/fstab/` settings?

Comment: is your SD card mounted read-only? (look for `ro` in the `mount` output). In that case your SD card is probably at the end of its life and has become read-only.

Comment: (unless of course the file system is simply damaged due to an unclean removal, and needs to be checked)

Comment: I `umount`ed and `mount`ed again the sd, but there was no output.

Comment: Check `dmesg` for mount problems

Comment: Hi and welcome! I'm not sure whether this is related, but `rsync -a` includes `-p`, `-g` and `-o`, which will probably not work on exfat. Maybe you should format the SDcard as ext4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xfat doesn't support file ownership or posix permissions.   If you just want to store file contents, you can have rsync do that.

If you want it to store file ownership/permissions as well, you'll want a different filesystem.